# Is there a word for when a word is pleasing to say?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when a word is pleasing to say?

I've found the word:

> Euphonious (of sound, especially speech) pleasing to the ear.

But I'm looking for one that is specifically nice to say.

E.g.

> Phychopathy
> Specificity

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "pleasing to say" and "specifically nice to say". Could you explain?  Also you ask, "Is there a word for when a word is pleasing to say?"  Do you want this word to be  a noun, a verb, or an adjective?  Please let us know.

Comment: *Mellifluous* isn't specific to words, but it gets there.

Comment: I suggest *dulciloquious* (I've just made it up and it fits the bill). *Dulci* means pleasing/sweet and *loqui* means to say/speak.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but a phrase - a particular word "rolls off the tongue" when it is pleasing to say.

As [the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/roll+off+the+tongue) explains:

> **roll off the tongue**
>
> To be very easy or enjoyable to say.
>
> *When you name your food truck, make sure it's something that **rolls off the tongue** so that people will remember it.*
>
> *The book is a joy to read aloud. The passages just **roll off the tongue**.*

Answer (score 0):

**Euphonious**

> OED
>
> **euphonious**, adj.
>
> Pronunciation:  Brit. /juːˈfəʊnɪəs/,  U.S. /juˈfoʊniəs/, /juˈfoʊnjəs/
>
> Etymology: formed as euphonical adj. + -ous suffix.
>
> **Full of or characterized by euphony; pleasing to the ear.**
>
> 1774   ‘J. Collier’ Musical Trav. 5   *I chose to change my name from Collier to Coglioni or Collioni, as more euphonious.*